# TFS Reporting Services

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, tfs

I installed TFS Server 2013 and I configured Sql Reporting Services after the TFS installation. All went well until I saw that Reporting Services is not seen by the TFS (in the browser, no url for reports are available) even if the wizard is showing me that Reporting Services are configured and enabled in TFS. When I follow the Reporting Services Url, I see that no TFS reports were created.

Has anyone else had this problem? Does anyone know the answer?

Employees had already introduced data into TFS so I can't just reinstall the server.

Please help!

Comment: Was the Team Project already created when you configured SSRS?  If so, you'll have to manually add the reports.

Comment: Did you mean you can't see any any url under Reporting Services Summary in Application Tier?  Did you mean you can't see TfsReports folder on http://tfsservername/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx? You may follow the steps on the website https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd631919(v=vs.120).aspx to configure the reporting service.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I solved the issue by  creating another Collection(DB). The SRSS was configured but there were no folders and reports created after finishing the configuration of SRSS. I guess that the configuration will not update the existing Collection with the new settings. Thank you for the support!

Answer (score 2):

Grab the [TFS Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f) and [download the process template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms181510%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) from the TFS server and then use:

> tfpt addprojectreports
>   /collection:"http://MyServer:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection"
>   /teamproject:MyProject /processtemplate:"TemplateName"

More details here:
[Upload reports to a team project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn130125(v=vs.120).aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your advice! :)